# Does Jammit require a JavaScript compressor on the production server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jammit

Does [Jammit](http://documentcloud.github.com/jammit/) require YUI Compressor or the Google Closure Compiler to be installed on the production server in order to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it doesn't.
It just requires the JVM (or equivalent, such as Open-JDK).

Jammit depends on two third-party Gems: one for Google Closure and one for YUI Compressor.
Both Gems are shipped with the corresponding compressor package bundled within the Gem.